# Microsoft.Identity.Client version 1.1.1-preview0040 doesn't work properly in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, authentication, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-msal

**Edit:** I've tried using the new preview version (1.1.2-preview0008) that just came out 2 days ago. The update didn't fix the issue that I'm experiencing.

I used Microsoft.Identity.Client version 1.0.303282006 for authentication in my Xamarin App but I have updated it to version 1.1.1-preview0040.

It behaves incorrectly now. After refactoring the code to work with version 1.1.1-preview0040, the app builds, but when the line of code for getting the token is run, `AcquireTokenAsync(Scopes)`, this exception is raised:

```
"Method 'Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenAsync' not found."
```

I tried other signatures of the same method. Right now, I’m using `_pca.AcquireTokenAsync(Scopes, uIParent)`. I can get uIParent from the Android App, but it doesn’t work 100%. It opens a login dialog, allows me to enter my username, then it shows a page saying “We’re unable to complete your request.”

I had a look at the url of this page and it indicates that there’s been an error:

> https://login.live.com/err.srf?lc=2057#error=invalid_request&error_description=The+provided+value+for+the+input+parameter+'redirect_uri'+is+not+valid.+The+expected+value+is+'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf'+or+a+URL+which+matches+the+redirect+URI+registered+for+this+client+application

I’ve tried other similar signatures of the same method and it always fails in the part where it’s supposed to ask me for my password. It seems like my Microsoft.Identity.Client nuget package can be found but it’s not being utilised properly.

From the looks of things, it seems like the preview version (1.1.1-preview0040) of Microsoft.Identity.Client isn’t working properly on the Xamarin App. However, I tried making a WinForms app and it works properly there so I'm not sure what caused this issue.

Comment: This looks more like a bug report than an actual question. You should be [reporting a bug report on the Microsoft github page](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues) with a repo of the issue in a xamarin project, not here.

Comment: I'm not certain this is a bug.  The error is saying the value you registered for your Redirect URI is different than what you specified in the request.  I believe Xamarin enforces the Redirect URI structure of `msal<client/app ID>://auth`.  I would check your app reg to make sure this is registered as a native/mobile app Redirect URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to follow the way the [Xamarin Forms Sample App](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2) set things up so I had to add more setup code in the Android Manifest and needed to set the redirect URI. `AcquireTokenAsync(IEnumerable<string> scopes` doesn't work anymore with Xamarin Apps so I had to use  `AcquireTokenAsync(IEnumerable<string> scopes, UIParent parent)`.

I also added a custom redirect URI in the [Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/) in the format `msal<clientId>://auth`.